# dataframe.empty gives "True" result, which should be "False" imo

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, boolean

With the help of Pandas I try to search for an ID in a column in a CSV file. I want the code to check if the dataframe is empty.

When I try the standalone code in Python3 it works fine. However, incorporated in the main code, the value that is returned is always "True". This is the strangest thing I have encountered so far.

```
def lookupID(ID):
    ID_df = df[df['ID'] == ID]
    ID_test = ID_df.empty
    return ID_test

df = pd.read_csv(mainFile, usecols=range(0,19))

for container in containers:
    ID = container.a["data-id"]


    if not lookupID(ID):
        code
    else:
        code
```

I hope someone knows what the hell is up with this one.

Some example rows with the headers included:

```
ID,merk,soort,prijs,bouwjaar,km-stand,transmissie,brandstof,inhoud,vermogen,plaatsnaam,distance,datum_begin,datum,prijs_oud,carroserie,kleur,titel,URL
124471366,BMW,2 Serie,19900,2015,25089,Handgeschakeld,Benzine,1499,100,Nieuwerkerk Ad Ijssel (ZH),116240,08/07/2019,08/07/2019,19900,MPV,Grijs,Active Tourer 218i High Executive Sport Line
124538604,BMW,1-serie,8900,2006,66914,Automaat,Benzine,1995,110,Heerlen (LI),134876,08/07/2019,08/07/2019,8900,Hatchback,Blauw,120i Anniversary / Automaat / Navigatie
124538344,BMW,3-serie,2900,2012,108390,Automaat,Diesel,1995,121,Haarlem (NH),131073,08/07/2019,08/07/2019,2900,Sedan,Grijs,320D Sedan High Exe-LEER-FINANCIAL LEASE VA 269| - PMND
```

Comment: Could you post some example rows from `df`? It would help to have a minimal and complete example that reproduces this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I edited my post and inserted a sample. I'm not sure if the format is any good.

Comment: What are the `containers`?

Comment: li elements extracted with bs4 from a webpage. So the containers are listings that contain an ID. I extract that ID and want to check in the CSV file if a row with the ID already exists.

Comment: What is the type of `ID` is it probably a float type? If so, please try, if you get the same, if you convert the column into an int type.